# Javascript, simple callback example not working as expected

Tags: javascript, callback, settimeout

First, thanks alot for anybody who will have a look at my question. It is totally basic but I just don`t get it. I have looked through all tutorials, but asynchronous callbacks drive me crazy.
Thank you so much for helping out, greetings from Germany :)

If somebody could tell me why below code does not log into the console as expected.
Expected means, callback is called after the Timeout function has completed.
Instead, my console logs the callback first?
What am I still getting wrong here?

```
function doHomework(subject, callback) {
  setTimeout(function () {
   console.log(`Starting my ${subject} homework.`);
  }, 10);
  callback();
}

doHomework('math', function() {
  console.log('Finished my homework');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you execute the callback outside of your `setTimeout` function. Javascript executes code asynchronously, meaning that it does not wait until the previous code is "finished" before it continues to the next line.

Hence, when you call `doHomework`, it will **start** the timer, and immediately continue to the next line of code, which is the callback.
Then, when the 10ms is over, the code inside the timeout is executed.
In order to get the desired result, you will have to place the callback execution inside the `setTimeout` function, like so:

```
function doHomework(subject, callback) {
   setTimeout(function () {
      console.log(`Starting my ${subject} homework.`);
      callback();
   }, 10);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Delvian, for your quick and precise answer. Though I understand your point, I still don´t understand it completely.
In putting the callback inside the Timeout (per definition then letting the callback being fired after the timeout) works BUT I thought Callbacks always make sure that something works synchronous.
If my console log would take more time (in case it would be a look up in a database) how make I sure that the callback is then fired afterwards as I do not know it by milliseconds. 
Sry in case it is confusing. Within {} something works syncronous?

Comment: Callbacks by themselves does not make anything synchronous. Callback is just a function that can be passed to another function and will run in some other place. And if it was a database lookup you'd just pass your callback further to that lookup function and it would run exactly afther this lookup.

Comment: I'm afraid not. The point of callbacks is that you only call them once you know you have set the preconditions needed.
In fact, the function that you pass to the `setTimeout` is in itself a callback.

For example, when you need data from an Ajax call before executing a function, you make sure that you execute that function as a callback at the moment when the data has been retrieved.

Comment: Thanks a lot to both of you!
@Delvian, your last sentence: How do I make sure that I execute the function as a callback AFTER the data has been retrieved. Do I manually set up a timeout?

Comment: @Aliaksandr,
var x = "lookUp some value";
Callback();

Comment: @AliaksandrSushkevich that would work? I thought javascript would not wait for the lookUp and would directly execute the Callback?

Comment: @betzebube1000 I made a very basic example of how to process data retrieved by an Ajax call using a callback function: https://jsfiddle.net/zv8ycuvc/

Comment: @betzebube1000, `var x = getData(callback)` - that would work. First the data is received then the callback is called with that data. So the callback is called inside getData function and data is passed inside the callback.

Comment: @betzebube1000 and you are right it wouldn't wait in your example, that's why we pass callbacks explicitly.

Comment: @Delvian thanks a lot for the example, I understand it in case of Ajax requests. I work with Node and Mongodb and just somehow it is never working. But you have helpedme a lot and I now need to do a lot of basic tutorials. Thanks!

Comment: @AliaksandrSushkevich Thanks for your reply ! I still don´t get, how we now that the data has been received. Thanks by the way for your proposed youube video. It is extremely helpful and I have learned a lot! Still there is some kind of misunderstanding in my head. But I guess, I just don`t have the bascis. When I build simply functions that get two arguments( one function and one callback function) the callback function still fires too early. But thanks a lot for all your help. Really apreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the call of a callback function inside your `setTimeout`

```
function doHomework(subject, callback) {
  setTimeout(function () {
   console.log(`Starting my ${subject} homework.`);
   callback();
  }, 10);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, Aliaksandr! As you see in the coment above, your solution works but I still don`t understand the concept of a callback I guess.... I tried to upvote you but due to my new profile it seems to be not possible. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try to watch this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ it has a really great explanation of how it works.